# Texlive 2013, where to place custom themes?

Tags: beamer, texlive

So I have installed TeXlive 2013 following the steps [here](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) I was previously using my custom theme called `beamerthemeEinstein.sty` that I placed at
    `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/theme` then I run
    `sudo texhash` and it worked amazingly.

Now with TeXlive 2013 my custom theme is not recognized, I get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeEinstein.sty' not found.
```

Where should I place   it now? Anyone knows where to place custom themes using the 2013 version? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have the folder `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/`? I use it to put my personal macros.

Comment: how about `~/texmf/tex/latex`?

Comment: AFAIK, the local folder hasn't changed and should be a subfolder of `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`, while the distribution is installed under `/usr/local/texlive/<year>`. Check that the correct TeX runtime is being used (`which pdflatex`) and that TeX can find your custom theme (`kpsewhich beamerthemeEinstein.sty`).

Comment: Thou shall not install your own files in `/usr/share`; see `man hier` and the [TeXLive documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-360003.4.6).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command

```
kpsexpand \$TEXMFLOCAL
```

will show you the path to the local system-wide tree which will not be modifed by updates of TL; it will usually be "next" to the texmf tree, as @sigur says.

```
kpsexpand \$TEXMFHOME
```

will show you the path to your user-specific tree, probably `/home/(username)/texmf`. (For more information, see [TeXlive docs on user texmf trees](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-360003.4.6), in particular the statement-by-omission that you don't need to refresh filename databases for new files in TEXMFHOME.

Comment: It is very strange... after exploring all my texlive 2013 folders, I found the themes at:
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme
However, if I type 'locate beamerthemedefault.sty' I get the place it was before:
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemedefault.sty
But there the theme is not present anymore...

I moved my custom theme along with the other ones at /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme and type 'sudo texhash' but still I get ! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeEinstein.sty' not found.

Comment: @Danicee: `locate` does not immediately update when you move files. Its database is usually updated as part of a cronjob, but this is leading us too far afield. Your custom themes should not live in the `texmf-dist` tree, they belong in -- guessing from the paths you give -- `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/beamer` (texhash needed, systemwide) or `~/texmf/tex/latex/beamer` (no texhash needed, your user only).